# How to handle incorrect git/hg clone command in ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, version-control, mercurial

Is there a way to handle trying to clone a repo that does not exist gracefully? In ruby, I can clone a repo like this:

```
system("hg clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repoThatDoesNotExist")
```

If the repo can be found, then it works fine. If it *cannot*, this error message pops up:

```
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Is there a way to handle these messages and continue on within the script instead of exiting? I've tried checking error codes and raising exceptions, but it still does not want to continue on with the rest.

Basically, I just want to be able to check if the repo that is trying to be cloned exists without exiting the script.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you comfortable using [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have never used that before, I'd prefer to not use Open3, but if that's the only way then I can

Comment: Did it finally work?

Comment: @SebastianPalma sorry for the delayed response! It did work. I tried it on my machine at work and it worked fine, i think its probably somethibg with the version of Mercurial or something like that that was causing an issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Open3#capture3 which gives you the status of the command, invoking `success?` then you can check if it threw an error or was successful.

```
require 'open3'

ERROR_MESSAGE = 'abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found'.freeze

def clone_repo(repo)
  _, _, status = Open3.capture3("hg clone #{repo}")

  return ERROR_MESSAGE unless status.success?
end

p clone_repo('https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repoThatDoesNotExist')
```

Comment: What does the _, _, in front of status mean?

Comment: Open3.capture3 returns three values, corresponding to the stdin, stdout, and stderr when running a command, we don't the the stdin nor stdout,  only the status, so it's a practice to tell that those values exist but we're not making use of them.

Comment: This does not seem to work when I replace 'git' with 'hg'. I have mercurial installed, but It still gives the 'ERROR_MESSAGE' when I use a repo that _does_ exist.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I tested with git. Are you sure the command runs successfully through the command line?

Comment: Yes, It runs perfectly fine straight through the command line. That makes me wonder if its something with capture3...

Comment: Can you print `"hg clone #{repo}"` before calling Open3.capture3? What does it return?

Comment: When I do: `p "hg clone #{repo}` it prints the exact thing I type in the command line (except with quotes). Strange. So in this case it'd look something like:         `"hg clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repoThatDoesExist"`.

Comment: If I do: `system("hg clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repoThatDoesExist")` it clones the repo just fine too

Comment: Can you try with `Open3.capture3('hg', 'clone', repo)`?

Comment: That gives me the same issue as well.

Comment: You can rename the variable for stdout and check the error is throwing when running `Open3.capture3`

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by that?

Comment: Use `_, stdout, status = Open3.capture3("hg clone #{repo}")` and print the value of stdout.